# git filter-repo: run lint-history without stopping on errors

Tags: prettier, git-filter-repo

I'm cleaning up a repo with the `lint-history` tool associated with `git-filter-repo`, applying Prettier to all commits:

```
python lint-history --relevant 'filename.endswith(b".ts")' prettier -w
```

It manages to process a few hundred commits, then crashes:

```
[error] ../../../../../var/abc123/somefile.ts: Expected valid tag name
[error]   30 |
[error]   31 |         <div>
[error] > 32 | <<<<<<< HEAD
[error]   33 |
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz/lint-history", line 174, in <module>
    filter.run()
  ...
  File "xyz/lint-history", line 132, in lint_with_real_filenames
    subprocess.check_call(lint_args.command + [filename.decode('utf-8')])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['prettier', '-w', '/var/abc13/somefile.ts']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
fatal: stream ends early
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_5034
```

It looks like the commit in question has some merge symbols (`<<<<<<< HEAD` and so on) that weren't resolved at the time. How can I make it so that Prettier leaves the file alone rather than exiting with an error code? Alternatively, can I get `lint-history` to continue despite the error from Prettier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by writing a script called `maybe-prettier`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env zsh

# Prettier gives three exit codes:
#  0 file is good
#  1 needs formatting
#  2 error

# Check the file and get the exit code. If the file needs
# formatting but doesn't produce an error, then format it.
prettier -c $1
if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
  prettier -w $1
fi
```

Then I can run `lint-history maybe-prettier`.